# Getting a custom navigation bar to re-size properly in web browser

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am trying my luck building a custom navigation bar for a site using silverlight. I like the way it looks but I am having trouble with it when it comes to size in an actual web page.
Here is how it looks
[image: rough version]

I am new to xaml and hence silverlight and so I am basically just looking for some tips on how to properly get this design to position and resize correctly. Here is the markup

```
<UserControl x:Class="SiteNavigationBar.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1500">


<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Stroke="#FF666666" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="11">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="20">
        <Rectangle RadiusY="7" RadiusX="7" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FFB1B1B1" Canvas.Left="21">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F7F7"  Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE8B13D"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Border>


    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="20">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                Home
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                About
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="4" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="15,0,0,0"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                Nutrition
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                Bloggers
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="5" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                Inspiration
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="6" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="24"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="Gray"
                       FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
                Contact
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </Grid>



    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.RowSpan="3"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Margin="170,10,170,10"
             Stroke="LightGray">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>

    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.RowSpan="3"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Margin="180,20,180,20"
             Stroke="LightGray">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3BC1FF" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>

    <Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
             Grid.RowSpan="3"
             Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
             Margin="200,40,200,40"
             Stroke="LightGray">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>

    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               FontSize="46"
               FontFamily="./fontscafe_marmellata-jam-demo.zip#Marmellata (Jam)_demo" Foreground="#FF898367">Bar</TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [ViewBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) you can reach this aim. Beside this I removed fixed FontSize expressions.

[image]

```
 <UserControl x:Class="SiteNavigationBar.MainPage"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="1500">

<Viewbox>
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>     
<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Stroke="#FF666666" RadiusY="15" RadiusX="15" StrokeThickness="2" Canvas.Top="50" Canvas.Left="11">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
<Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="20">
    <Rectangle RadiusY="7" RadiusX="7" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="#FFB1B1B1" Canvas.Left="21">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F7F7"  Offset="1"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE8B13D"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Border>


<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            Home
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            About
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="4" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="15,0,0,0"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            Nutrition
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,15,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            Bloggers
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="5" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            Inspiration
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Column="6" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
            BorderBrush="LightGray">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"

                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Gray"
                   FontFamily="./gluk_foglihten.zip#Foglihten.otf">
            Contact
        </TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>



<Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.RowSpan="3"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
         Margin="170,10,170,10"
         Stroke="LightGray">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>

<Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.RowSpan="3"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
         Margin="180,20,180,20"
         Stroke="LightGray">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF3BC1FF" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>

<Ellipse Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.RowSpan="3"
         Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
         Margin="200,40,200,40"
         Stroke="LightGray">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C4C4" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>

<TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"

           FontFamily="./fontscafe_marmellata-jam-demo.zip#Marmellata (Jam)_demo" Foreground="#FF898367">Bar</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I actually did attempt to use a viewbox before I went to bed last night but I only gave it 2 minutes of "fedangling". I do not like how it "smooshes" my bar and constrains the ellipses to the rectangle's used to create the bar. I will try to mess with it some more tonight and get back here with feed back and hopefully a checked answer.